# Using the same text section several times in r markdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I´m working on an html document using r markdown. My document is divided into several types of projects and several chapters, whereas some chapters are the same for all types of projects, and some are different. For example:

[chapter flow example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMmIn.png)

So swapping between project types is not a problem using `tabset`, but I can´t manage to reuse the same (text) section in several places (e.g. preface, chapter B or End in the picture).
Selecting project type in each of the chapters is a possibility, but since there are really a lot of chapters, it´s not so user friendly. Creating separate markdown files and embedding them into one would probably also be a possibility, but it makes the frequent editing required a real annoyance.

I would imagine it more or less like this:

```
<preface define the preface without it actually appearing> preface...preface </preface>
<a1 define chapter a1 without it actually appearing> abc def </a1>
<a2 define chapter a2 without it actually appearing> ghi jkl mnop </a2>
<a3 define chapter a3 without it actually appearing> qrs tuv wxyz </a3>
<end define the last chapter without it actually appearing> end... end </end>

# document {.tabset .tabset-fade}
## Project 1 {-}
<preface>
<a1></a1>
<end>

## Project 2 {-}
<preface>
<a2></a2>
<end>

## Project 3 {-}
<preface>
<a3></a3>
<end>
```

But I can´t find a way to define & reuse a text section (only a code section).

I´m searching the web for hours now and can´t get my hands around it - anything I´m missing?
**Is there any way of repeating a large content section in several places in an r-markdown document?**

Thank you so much in advance,

Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this gives you an idea of how to get what you want:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is text typed directly into the document.

```{r}
reusableText <- "This is text stored in an R object for re-use."
```

Reusable text can be included in the body of the document outside a chunk
by referring to it in inline code `r` ` ` `reusableText`, like this:
`r reusableText`. The same object can be referenced more than once: `r reusableText`

The reusable text can contain formatting an section headers:

```{r}
reusableSectionWithFormatting <- "#  Section title<br><i>Italic text.</i> Normal Text." 
```

`r reusableSectionWithFormatting`
`r reusableSectionWithFormatting`
````

Producing:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that´s exactly what I was trying to do! I actually thought it would be a problem using large text blocks with diverse formatting as an R object, but it seems to work perfectly, even the numbering is embedded in the numbering of the rest of the document. Great!

Comment: I'm happy to have helped.  Please accept my answer (click on the tick at top left) to indicate to other users that you have a solution.  That helps both potential helpers and those seeking answers to similar problems.